# css :target selector vs new page

Tags: css, web-analytics

I'm building a page using ":target" pseudo-selectors linking to different content and resulting in bookmarkable hash-marked "pages"
For example:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#history">History</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="pages">  
  <div id="home">...</div>
  <div id="history">...</div>
  <div id="news">...</div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering how this affects page hits and search engine ranking, compared to links to unique pages. I assume as long as the href is to content on the same page, it only counts as one hit. True?

Comment: Possibly a better fit for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to call `_trackPageview` if **you** want to register these as different page hits. Google Analytics will not automatically capture these events and will treat it as a single page otherwise.

Comment: So, I can track the different hits myself but, as far as THE WEB is concerned, it's just one page hit?